# "OnMouseDown" not firing after converting resources to download bundle

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm facing a strange issue, in my game i'm using `OnMouseDown` for click and drag etc everything working fine but once converting resources to download bundle (for downloading) it's not working any more and the rest of the script is working fine means `Update` etc functions are working.

note:Script is attached with the prefab which later on Instantiated in game to create objects.

using `Bundle Assets From Selection - Track Dependency`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart the unity3d and up,down and drag are working now. :)